# Найти сумму чисел в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list

```
lis = [10000, 2000, 1250]
```

Хочу чтобы эти элементы сложились и вывело `13250` (`10000 + 2000 + 1250`).

Comment: `sum(lis)`..................

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самый короткий способ

```py
print(sum(lis))
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вот:

```
import functools, operator

lis = [10000, 2000, 1250] 
print(functools.reduce(operator.add, lis))
```

Comment: в данном случае это, по-моему, явный перебор. Гораздо идиоматичнее воспользоваться `sum(lis)`...

Comment: @MaxU `sum(lis)` уже используется в 2 ответах и комментарии

Answer (score 2):

```
lis = [10000, 2000, 1250]
sum = 0 
for i in lis:
    sum += i
print(sum)
```

Так можете потренироваться в итерационных объектах

Comment: после выполнения данного кода вы не сможете воспользоваться встроенной функцией `sum()`! Не надо затенять встроенные функции / классы / модули

Answer (score 1):

А так можете потренироваться в использовании метода range:

```
lis = [10000, 2000, 1250]
sum = 0 

for i in range(len(lis)): # Аргумент: Стоп
    sum += lis[i]

print(sum)
```

Так с конца:

```
lis = [10000, 2000, 1250]
sum = 0 

for i in range(len(lis)-1, -1, -1): # Аргументы: Старт, Стоп, Шаг
    sum += lis[i]

print(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

- ```
  lis = [10000, 2000, 1250]
  print(sum(lis))
  ```

- ```
  lis = [10000, 2000, 1250]
  sum = 0
  for i in lis:
      sum += i
      print(sum)
  ```

Comment: Зачем вы это написали всё?

Comment: Во втором примере сумма выводиться каждую итерацию, мне кажется это ошибка.